# allow to select only one radiobutton

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a survey with 6 questions. Each question will be rated between (1-5). I want to capture the value selected for each question. Only one value can be selected on each question
The following is allowing me to select more than one option for each question, I should restrict to select only one for each question. All the radio buttons should be grouped as one, and only one button can be selected. I should be able to capture the selected value for each when submitted.

```
public class SurveyViewModel
{
    public GroupViewModel GroupA { get; set; }
    public GroupViewModel GroupB { get; set; }
    public GroupViewModel GroupC { get; set; }
    public SurveyViewModel()
    {
        GroupA = new GroupViewModel();
        GroupA.GroupName = "A";
        GroupB = new GroupViewModel();
        GroupB.GroupName = "B";
        GroupC = new GroupViewModel();
        GroupC.GroupName = "C";
    }
}

public class GroupViewModel
{
    public string GroupName { get; set; }
    public bool radio1 { get; set; }
    public bool radio2 { get; set; }
    public bool radio3 { get; set; }
    public bool radio4 { get; set; }
    public bool radio5 { get; set; }
}
```

Editor Template:

```
<div>
    <h4>GroupViewModel</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.radio1, true, new { id = Model.GroupName + "1" })</dt>
        <dd>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.radio1)</dd>
        <dt>@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.radio2, true, new { id = Model.GroupName + "2" })</dt>
        <dd>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.radio2)</dd>
        <dt>@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.radio3, true, new { id = Model.GroupName + "3" })</dt>
        <dd>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.radio3)</dd>
        <dt>@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.radio4, true, new { id = Model.GroupName + "4" })</dt>
        <dd>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.radio4)</dd>
        <dt>@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.radio5, true, new { id = Model.GroupName + "5" })</dt>
        <dd>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.radio5)</dd>
    </dl>
</div>
```

and the survey View as follows:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{ 
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.GroupA)
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.GroupB)
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.GroupC)
    <input type="submit" value="Continue" />
}
```

I have added a group name as posted below, but I could not able to capture the selected value in the http post

```
 @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.radio1, true, new { id = Model.GroupName + "1", @Name = Model.GroupName })
```

Comment: Can you post the generated html for the survey view ?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It worked great. How do I validate to force user to select one answer for each question. Default value of Rating is 0, I cannot use Required attribute since there won't be nullable values. Should I change the int property Rating as nullable (int?). If I change it to nullable, then I would have to make amendments to lot of change. Is there any way we can validate with the existing property?

Answer (score 1):

You have to override the name attribute:

```
 @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.radio1, true, new { id = Model.GroupName + "1", @Name = "Group" })
```

You have to do this for every radiobutton that you want to have only one selection.

When you use `Html.RadioButtonFor` it expected that you use the same property to bind all radio buttons like:

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.radio, "answer1")
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.radio, "answer2")
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.radio, "answer3")
```

Or using an Enumeration in place of "answer1", "answer2" and "answer3"

Comment: I have changed it to @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.radio1, true, new { id = Model.GroupName + "1", @Name = Model.GroupName }), that has allowed me to capture one radio button for each question, but the selected values are not captured in http post.

Comment: @Rama The values were empty? Before was capturing?

Answer (score 0):

Each radio button you generating if for a different property and has a different name (they are not grouped) so all radio buttons within a 'Question' can be selected, and worse, none of then can be unselected once selected.

In addition your properties within `SurveyViewModel` are all the same type, so you should be using a collection property, not generating individual properties for each item.

Start by creating a view model which represents what you want to display/edit in the view.

```
public class QuestionVM
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMesage = "Please select a rating")]
    public int? Rating { get; set; }
}
```

and in the controller GET method

```
List<QuestionVM> model = new List<QuestionVM>()
{
    new QuestionVM() { Name = "A" },
    new QuestionVM() { Name = "B" },
    new QuestionVM() { Name = "C", Rating = 3 } // use this if you want to pre-select a radio button
};
return View(model);
```

Next, create an `EditorTemplate` for `QuestionVM`. The templates needs to be named `/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/QuestionVM.cshtml`

```
@model QuestionVM
<div class="question">
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Name) // so this value posts back
    <h2>@Model.Name</h2>
    @for(int i = 1; i < 6; i++)
    {
        <label>
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Rating, i, new { id = "" })// remove id attribute to prevent invalid html
            <span>@i</span>
        </label>
    }
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Rating)
</div>
```

and finally in the main view

```
@model IEnumerable<QuestionVM>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m)
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

which will post back to

```
public ActionResult Edit(IEnumerable<QuestionVM model) // adjust method name to suit
```